# Finding the Root of a Polynomial using Multiple Root Theorem

Tags: polynomials

Solve the equation $x^4+2x^3-12x^2+14x-5 = 0$.

I have found that there is a triple root at $1$ and a single root at $-5$.
However I am unsure of the working out and formatting of my solution.

Comment: Compute $(x-1)^3(x+5)$ ? If it coincides with your  polynomial, you're good...

Comment: Use the unique factorisation property for polynomials over $\mathbf Z$. Or divide by $x+5$: the quotient should correspond to an identity.